# Hangfire ContinueWith with multiple sources

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, hangfire

I am chewing on a way to accomplish the following using **ContinueWith**:

1. Originating App submits a (NonConcurrent) Job
2. Job starts up, does a little processing, calls a Web Service elsewhere
3. Job "completes" (goes quiescent)
4. Web Service submits a "continuation" job after it is done with its internal processing (could be 30 minutes, could be 2 days)
5. A Jobs.ContinueWith is called somehow?
6. Job finally completes, original job is marked as complete

What I am running into is too many moving parts.  Originating App is a C#/MVC app.  User does his thing and at the end submits a long running job to be executed.  The Job Processor (C# library) does a little bit of work then calls a JAVA SOAP endpoint delivering the results of the initial processing.  The JAVA SOAP endpoint calls a COTS app to do the brunt of the processing then calls back to the job with an "I'm done".

As you can see, I don't have a clear way to do the following:

```
var parentId = _jobs.Enqueue<MyJob>(x => x.StartExecution(job.Id));
_jobs.ContinueWith<JAVA_ENDPOINT>(parentId, x => x.JAVA_EXECUTION(job.Id));  // this part is not in my control!
_jobs.ContinueWith<MyJob>(parentId, x => x.ContinueExecution(job.Id));
```

I do have a REST service (POST) that I am using as the only way to start a job.  Basically, pass in a well formed payload (JSON) and the controller picks the Job object from an IoC container, decides which type of job it is (AdHoc, Recurring, Continuation, etc) then executes the proper Hangfire call(s) to Enqueue it.  The JAVA Endpoint can easily call to this REST service as well.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post()
{
    // safety checks removed for brevity...
    var command = new MinimumCommandModel(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    return GetPostPipeline().Handle(command).Id;
}

private static IRequestHandler<MinimumCommandModel, MinimumResultModel> GetPostPipeline()
{
    return new MediatorPipeline<MinimumCommandModel, MinimumResultModel>
        (new QueuePostMediator()
            , new IPreRequestHandler<MinimumCommandModel>[]
            {
                new PreJobLogger(),
                new PreJobExistsValidator(),
                new PreJobPropertiesValidator()
            }
            , new IPostRequestHandler<MinimumCommandModel, MinimumResultModel>[]
            {
                new PostJobLogger()
            }
        );
}
```

The QueuePostMediator handles the specifics of the job type (AdHoc, et al).  I am trying to write the continuation handler now and am a bit stymied by how to go about this.  I certainly don't want to do any sort of blocking actions outside of Hangfire.  I'm not sure how to "start" another job as a continuation of the original job when they are not originally connected with the parentId of the originating job.

Basically, if I could, from inside the job, put the job on hold until an outside stimulus told hangfire to continue the job I would be golden.  I have not yet cracked how to accomplish this though.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: I would split MyJob into 2 parts - the one running before JAVA and one running after that. You can enqueue a job from another job - so why not just start job MyJob, as its continuation the JAVA job and this one would trigger MyJobContinuation when its finished. From your description it looks like the job does different stuff anyway before and after the JAVA call. If your concern is about the concurrency, you can create a custom Hangfire Attribute that makes sure, that two different jobs are not running simultaneously - if you are interested into that, I can provide more details how.

Comment: Yes, concurrency is one of my concerns.  The entire job has to complete before another job of this type can start.  Mainly because the COTS piece is CPU, memory & time intensive - and it is single threaded.  The JAVA endpoint is nothing more than a wrapper as the COTS piece only has JAVA hooks.  :(

Comment: I think I will try to look through the Hangfire code to see if there is a way to put a job into a "on hold" status, then add an override for the Continuation that will allow the 1st job to "finish", run the 2nd part and then complete the whole (if that makes sense).

Comment: this will probably not work without additional effort. A job is technically just a running thread. You cannot put that 'on hold' and continue just like that. You have to build a semaphore for this in one job and control it from the 2nd one (which is of course possible). To make sure that 2 different Jobs do not run simultaneously, you have to create own Hangfire Attribute - just copy the original DisableConcurrentExecution and change the part acquiring lock where you define your own string - using such attribute on more Jobs will make sure that none of them will run at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I have figured out a hack to get this to work.

I am using a strategy pattern to run different parts of each job. I have a JobStatus called Handoff and now do this:

```
public class Processing : BaseJobExecutor<PayloadModel>, IJobExecutor<PayloadModel>
{
    public Processing(JobPingPong job) : base(job, JobStatus.Processing) {}

    public void Handle()
    {
        JobInfo.JobStatus = JobStatus.ExtProcessing;
        JobInfo.HangfireParentJobId = JobInfo.HangfireJobId;
        Payload.PostToQueueText(@"http://localhost:8080/api/clone");

        // Pause the current job (this is the parent job) so the outside web service has a chance to complete...
        var enqueuedIn = new TimeSpan(0, 6, 0, 0);  // 6 hours out...
        JobPutOnHold(JobInfo.HangfireJobId, enqueuedIn);

        // The next status to be executed upon hydration...
        JobInfo.JobStatus = JobStatus.Complete;
        Job.CachePut();

        // Signal the job executor that this job is "done" due to an outside process needing to run...
        JobInfo.JobStatus = JobStatus.Handoff;
    }
}
public void JobPutOnHold(string jobId, TimeSpan enqueuedIn)
{
    var jobClient = new BackgroundJobClient();
    jobClient.ChangeState(jobId, new ScheduledState(enqueuedIn));
}
```

Now, in the strategy executor I can do this:

```
public string Execute(IServerFilter jobContext, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (Payload.JobInfo.JobStatus != JobStatus.Done)
    {
        cancellationToken?.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        var jobStrategy = new JobExecutorStrategy<TPayload>(Executors);
        Payload = jobStrategy.Execute(Payload);

        if (Payload.JobInfo.JobStatus == JobStatus.Handoff)
            break;
    }
    return PayloadAsString;
}
```

The 2nd part of the job fires off the same as the 1st part but comes in from the outside service with an ExtComplete status, which allows the job to execute the post processing based on the results from the outside world (stored in the DB). Like this:

```
public class ExtComplete : BaseJobExecutor<PayloadModel>, IJobExecutor<PayloadModel>
{
    public ExtComplete(JobPingPong job) : base(job, JobStatus.ExtComplete) { }

    public void Handle()
    {
        // do post processing here...
        Payload.Tokens = null;
        JobInfo.JobStatus = JobStatus.Complete;
        if (JobInfo.HangfireJobId != JobContext.JobId || JobInfo.HangfireParentJobId == JobInfo.HangfireJobId)
        {
            JobInfo.HangfireParentJobId = JobInfo.HangfireJobId;
            JobInfo.HangfireJobId = JobContext.JobId;
        }

        // Enqueue the previous (parent) job so it can complete...
        JobExecuteNow(JobInfo.HangfireParentJobId);
    }
}
public void JobExecuteNow(string jobId)
{
    var enqueuedIn = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15);
    var jobClient = new BackgroundJobClient();
    jobClient.ChangeState(jobId, new ScheduledState(enqueuedIn));
}
```

Eventually, the timing will be config driven, but for now I am setting it to have the 1st job pick up execution in 15 seconds.

The only challenge I faced with this approach is the job payload that comes in is the original payload before any processing happened. That is why you see the "caching" up above. When the job restarts I check to see if a cache exists for that Hangfire JobId, if it does, load up the last known payload from cache then allow the executor to go on its merry way.

Works very well so far.

NOTE: I am still trying to learn how to alter/inject the Chain of Command and State Objects in Hangfire to make this more internal to hangfire. We have one job that makes a dozen or more outside calls. Currently, it takes about 12 hours to run.